# Return the larger value in the in the given range

Tags: java, if-statement, operators

While I was practicing on the Coding bat I came across this question which I got stuck at.
Given two positive integer values, return the larger value that is in the range of 10...20(inclusive), or return 0 if neither is in that range.
max1020(11,19)--> 19

max1020(19,11)--> 19

max1020(11,9)--> 11

Can you help me what went wrong with my solution:-

```
public int max1020(int a, int b) {
  if((a>=10&&a<=20)||(b>=10&&b<=20)){
    int max;
    if(a>b){
      max=a;
    }else{
      max=b;
    }
    return max;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not handling the case where the lower number is in the range of 10 to 20, but the higher number is out of that range. In that case you should return the lower number, but you return the higher number, which is out of range.

When your `if((a>=10&&a<=20)||(b>=10&&b<=20))` condition is true, there are 3 possibilities:

1. both a and b are between 10 and 20, in which case you should return the larger of them
2. only a is between 10 and 20, in which case you should return a (even if b is higher)
3. only b is between 10 and 20, in which case you should return b (even if a is higher)

You can write something like this:

```
public int max1020(int a, int b) {
  if (a >= 10 && a <= 20) {
      if (b >= 10 && b <= 20) {
          return a > b ? a : b;
      } else {
          return a;
      }
   } else {
      if (b >= 10 && b <= 20)) {
          return b;
      } else {
          return 0;
      }
   }
}
```